# django ModelForm for subclassed models : Error for one, but not for another ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'label')

Tags: django, django-forms

I'd like to ask for you guidance in the following matter in django:

I am using the following models:

```
class QItem(models.Model):
    isWhat = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,  choices=ISWHAT)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    script = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)

class QuestionSet(QItem):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(QItem, blank=True, through='Ordering',related_name="contained")


class Question(QItem):
    answerObject = models.OneToOneField("AnswerObject", blank=True, null=True)
```

and their respective, most basic ModelForms:

```
class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question

class QuestionSetForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = QuestionSet
```

In a view, calling

```
           qset=QuestionFormSet()
           print q
```

works just fine.

However,

```
           q = QuestionForm()
           print q
```

throws

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label'
```

in Django's server. When trying it in the console, I don't get any errors.
Edit : Also, modelform_factory(Question) works.

Any ideas why this is the case? Why do similar models behave so differently, and how could I get rid of the error?

Edit :
This is the full Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/dj1/../dj1/esm/views.py" in dashboard
  193.  print qForm
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in **str**
  27.         return self.**unicode**().encode('utf-8')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in **unicode**
  95.         return self.as_table()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in as_table
  217.             errors_on_separate_row = False)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _html_output
  145.             bf = BoundField(self, field, name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in **init**
  398.         if self.field.label is None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /esm/dashboard/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label'

Comment: It works well to me. Do your app validate? Is that trough="Ordering" well defined? Please post the full backtrace!

Comment: Yes, please post more of the traceback.

Comment: Yes, the model does validate, and all the models seem to work well together.
The interesting thing is that creating the form through modelform_factory does not produce any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have something like `fields = ("name")` in the Meta of your Modelform ?
The above statement is treated as an expression and not as a tuple. So the code is looking to validate field 'n','a','m','e' in the example above, as opposed to "name".

Please use a trailing comma to force python to interpret the Meta field above as a tuple `fields = ("name",)` ... your code should work fine after this change.